# Dynamic require a module by string

Tags: node.js, webpack

```
require('Something') //working fine
require(`${dynamicName}`) //not work with node prompt for out of memory
```

Can advise on how to dynamically require a module based on variable 'dynamicName' ?

Comment: What's wrong with `require(dynamicName)`?

Comment: this is the error i get   WARNING in ./src ^\.\/.*$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
 @ ./src ^\.\/.*$

Comment: Are you passing a regex to the `require` function?

Comment: my last tried was with require(dynamicName) which shows the error

Comment: Ok, but I can see that `dynamicName` consists a regex and that way it is not gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always override `require` with your own version, since it is a function.

```
function setupMyRequire() {
    var tmpreq = global.require;
    global.require = function(name) {
        // parse name here
        console.log('will require', name);
        tmpreq(name);
    };
}
```